# How I can deactivate the Ibus Input Method on Ubuntu Gnome?

Tags: gnome, ibus, input-method

I need to deactivate for use office on Wine. The option don't shows up when I go to Region & Language, this option appears on Ubuntu Unity, but don't on Ubuntu Gnome

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "Input Method" tool, which is the GUI of the `im-config` package. To open `im-config` simply run that name in Terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>), click <kbd>OK</kbd> on the first window you get, then on the second select <kbd>Yes</kbd> which should take you to a section which looks like this (there may be some differences between our systems in this section):

[image: Input Method Configuration Panel im-config]

In this section you will be able to select (as you can see) a different input method from ibus if you so wish.